# Laravel middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una duda un poco tonta, la cuestión es que me dispongo a crear el filtro por roles en Laravel, he creado un middleware de para el filtro de roles en las rutas y hasta aquí todo OK.

El problema viene cuando quiero realizar este filtro

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'],'roles' => ['cliente','cliente_tipo2'],'prefix' => 'descargas'], function () { 
    // Index
    Route::get('/', 'DescargasController@indexView')->name('indexDescargas');
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'],'roles' => ['cliente_tipo2'],'prefix' => 'privado'], function () { 
        Route::get('/', 'DescargasController@privadoView')->name('indexDescargasprivado');
    });
});
```

La cuestión, es que para entrar a la raíz al primer / dentro del primer grupo, controla esos dos roles OK (no deja entrar a otros), el problema surge en el segundo grupo, que en lugar de dejar pasar solo al rol "cliente_tipo2" deja pasar a todos los del grupo de arriba (en este caso "cliente" y "cliente_tipo2") a pesar de estar en otro grupo con otro middleware.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: no puedes usar el mismo middleware dentro de si mismo. porque el que prevalece es el primero.

Comment: Osea, que creando otro totalmente igual, con distinto nombre, ¿Funciona? Voy a probar. Gracias Jorge Bowen

Comment: O quitando el de dentro y colocando afuera , intentalo y me dices que tal te fue.

Comment: Hecho Jorge Browen, el problema de quitar el de fuera era la duplicidad de las rutas, lo cual no me parecía lo más correcto, he creado otro Middelware llamandole "subroles" y lo he hecho funcionar a la perfección.

Mil gracias.

Comment: Me alegro mucho.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gracias al compañero Jorge Bowen el problema era por utilizar el mismo middelware dentro de otro.

Así quedó:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'],'roles' => ['cliente','cliente_tipo2'],'prefix' => 'descargas'], function () { 
    // Index
    Route::get('/', 'DescargasController@indexView')->name('indexDescargas');
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'subroles'],'subroles' => ['cliente_tipo2'],'prefix' => 'privado'], function () { 
        Route::get('/', 'DescargasController@privadoView')->name('indexDescargasprivado');
    }); });
```

A petición del compañero del primer comentario, edito como quedó finalmente, simplemente duplique la clase de los Middleware, cambiando "roles" por "subroles" para que no fuera la misma clase y funcionase bien.

Muy recomendado para permisos que dependen de otros, o, para no duplicar URLs.

Saludos

Comment: Me alegro de que solucionaras el problema. Deberías editar la respuesta para compartir cómo quedo el filtro al final con los cambios que hiciste, de ese modo si otro usuario se encuentra con un problema similar en el futuro, esta respuesta le serviría mejor. Lee [answer] para más información.